# Finding the upper and lower Riemann sum

Tags: calculus

How would I solve the following problem?

Find the lower and upper Riemmann sums $Lf(P)$ and $Uf(P)$ for the function $f(x)=\sin(x)$ on $[0,\frac{3\pi}{2}]$

using the partition $[0,\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{2\pi}{3},\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}]$

for my Lf(P) I got $(0)\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{5\pi}{12}+0\frac{\pi}{3}+(-1)\frac{\pi}{2}=-36.9669$

for my $Uf(P)$ I got

$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{5\pi}{12}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{\pi}{3}+(0)\frac{\pi}{2}$

$Uf(P)=148.73323$

But would this be correct?

Answer (score 1):

The terms in your sums are correct but sums are wrong--- presumably because you  took $\pi$ = 180.

The upper and lower sum corresponding to P must be $L_P=-0.645...$ and $U_P$= $ 2.5958$ ...

Note that you must take $\pi$ = $3.141592$... [not $180$]